# Is it possible to spool to a file everything is typed from a windows terminal and its output?

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm wondering whether is possible or not to spool to a file everything is typed from a Windows CMD terminal in order to record my work activity. I need to spool to the same file even what is performed from  other interactive command line tools invoked from the terminal like Oracle SQL*Plus or any progamming language REPL like tool.

The goal is mainly to save some investigation activities made on a server for troubleshooting performance issues, so I can review all the metrics collected for each step after the issue is eventually disappeared.

Even if not useful at the moment, it would be nice to know how to do the same on both Unix/Linux and Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

You could start a PowerShell session and use:

```
Start-Transcript -Path $Env:USERPROFILE/mylog.txt
& "$Env:ComSpec" /K
REM enter commands and run batch files...
EXIT
Stop-Transcript

Get-Content -Path "$Env:USERPROFILE/mylog.txt"
```

The commands will not be in the mylog.txt file until after you exit the cmd.exe shell. I have no idea if it will work in the same way on Linux or Mac. I have not thought about it much.

If you need to record multiple shell sessions, they will probably need to write to different log files.